# Taking fixed values from CSV file turn by turn in Netlogo

Tags: csv, netlogo

I am struggling to write an irrigation model. I want turtles to take values from CSV file with the ticks. There are 100 values in the list. I want  10 turtles to pick first  (let us say 20) value turn by turn ie., turtle 0, 1,2 3 .. will take first value in the list turn by turn  (with every tick) and after the 10th ticks all turtles will take 2nd value (as 22) so on and so forth. Concept is  related to water demand which is fixed and will change after 10 days for every turtle. 100 values will be consumed in 1000 ticks
Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking a new question, it really should be asked as a new question, not as an add-on to an old one.  But let me answer it here.  I've taken your code above and made some changes. First, I've taken the `setxy` asks out of the create-farmers block.  Anything in that block is executed by each of the created farmers so, in this case, it is executed 10 times.  Next, try if at all you can to avoid `who` numbers.  You almost never need them.  In particular, `farmers-list` contains the sorted list of farmers and you can simply use it to ask the proper farmer directly to set its demand.  Also, you don't need each farmer to set `list-element` as it is the same for all farmers in any given tick.  You have two `tick` commands - you only want one. And, finally, you see that I've simplified your `file-read` command. In your case, `file-read` returns a single value, which you can just add to the list.

```
Breed [farmers farmer]
globals [demand-list  IWR-perday farmers-list]
farmers-own [current-demand irrigation-turn ]

    to setup
      clear-all
      create-farmers 10 [ set irrigation-turn [0] ]
      ask farmer 0 [ setxy min-pxcor + 1 0]
      ask farmer 1 [ setxy min-pxcor + 3 0]
      ask farmer 2 [ setxy min-pxcor + 5 0]
      ask farmer 3 [ setxy min-pxcor + 7 0]
      ask farmer 4 [ setxy min-pxcor + 9 0]
      ask farmer 5 [ setxy min-pxcor + 11 0]
      ask farmer 6 [ setxy min-pxcor + 13 0]
      ask farmer 7 [ setxy min-pxcor + 15 0]
      ask farmer 8 [ setxy min-pxcor + 17 0]
      ask farmer 9 [ setxy min-pxcor + 19 0]
      set farmers-list sort turtles
      import-data 
      reset-ticks
      
    end

to go
  let list-element floor ticks / 10 
  ask item (ticks mod 10) farmers-list [
    set current-demand item list-element IWR-perday
  ]
  show map [c -> [current-demand] of c] farmers-list
  tick
end

to import-data  
  ;; Import water demand
  ifelse ( file-exists? "IWR-perday.txt" )
  [
    set IWR-perday []
    file-open "IWR-perday.txt"
    while [ not file-at-end? ]
    [
      set IWR-perday lput file-read IWR-perday
    ]
    file-close
    show IWR-perday
  ]
  [ user-message "There is no IWR-perday.txt file in current directory!" ]
end
```

I think if you run this with your data file, which I did to check it out, you will see that within each set of ten ticks, the demand of the ten turtles is set one by one.  With over 1000 values in `IWR-perday`, that will go on for over 10,000 ticks!

Comment: This is supposed to end by 10000 ticks app as this contains water requirement of crop in every 10 days for number of years. Thank you for the help. This means a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some code that might get you started.  I've abstracted from the CSV file by simply creating a list, `demand-list`, of random demand numbers - you would read them in from the CSV file at the beginning of your simulation.  From that point, ten turtles are created with a `turtles-own` variable, `demand`, and put into a list sorted by `who` number.

The `go` procedure uses the current tick and the `floor` operator to find which element of the demand-list is the proper one for this set of ten ticks, and the `mod` operator determines which turtle (consumer) in the consumer list should, at this tick, take that value for its `demand`.  The `show` simply shows the demand of each turtle at the end of each tick.

```
globals [demand-list consumer-list]
turtles-own [demand]

to setup
  clear-all
  set demand-list n-values 100 [random 50]
  create-turtles 10 [set demand 0]
  set consumer-list sort turtles
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  let list-element floor ticks / 10
  let chosen-consumer ticks mod 10
  ask item chosen-consumer consumer-list [set demand item list-element demand-list]
  show map [c -> [demand] of c] consumer-list
  tick
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Charles. I have translated in my model and  program is working well. I want to ask one more thing. I am adding below in answer. please advise.

Answer (score 0):

[IWR-perday](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E3RGLus4H7jyeMPn_JCs5XXofpiNP9xR/view?usp=sharing) is a CSV file. I want to ask if I don't sort  and don't write farmer's list! How this will be shown in show map to see if codes are working fine.

```
Breed [farmers farmer]
globals [demand-list  IWR-perday farmers-list]
farmers-own [current-demand irrigation-turn ]

to setup
  clear-all
       create-farmers 10 [ set irrigation-turn [0]
                      ask farmer 0 [ setxy min-pxcor + 1 0]
                      ask farmer 1 [ setxy min-pxcor + 3 0]
                      ask farmer 2 [ setxy min-pxcor + 5 0]
                      ask farmer 3 [ setxy min-pxcor + 7 0]
                      ask farmer 4 [ setxy min-pxcor + 9 0]
                      ask farmer 5 [ setxy min-pxcor + 11 0]
                      ask farmer 6 [ setxy min-pxcor + 13 0]
                      ask farmer 7 [ setxy min-pxcor + 15 0]
                      ask farmer 8 [ setxy min-pxcor + 17 0]
                      ask farmer 9 [ setxy min-pxcor + 19 0]]
                       set farmers-list sort turtles
  import-data 
    reset-ticks

end

to go
  
foreach [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ] [ ?1 ->
  ask farmers with [who = ?1] [let list-element floor ticks / 10 
      set current-demand item list-element IWR-perday]]
      show map [c -> [current-demand] of c] farmers-list
  tick
    tick
end
to import-data
    
    ;; Import water demand
  ifelse ( file-exists? "IWR-perday.txt" )
  [
    set IWR-perday []
    file-open "IWR-perday.txt"
    while [ not file-at-end? ]
    [
      *set IWR-perday sentence IWR-perday (list file-read)
    ]
    file-close
  ]
  [ user-message "There is no IWR-perday.txt file in current directory!" ]
end*
```